# the_post_thumbnail fallback using hooks

Tags: functions, post-thumbnails

I am using this big theme that is almost entirely relying on widgets and sliders.
Now I trying to avoid looking for `post_thumbnail` output code in all the included files in order to achieve fallback which should then grab first image in post or at last display default image.

Is there a way of controlling this via `functions` file?

Any help appreciated.

**Solution based on `post_thumbnail_html` `filter hook` doesn't display featured image if it is not explicitly set:**

```
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'my_post_thumbnail_fallback', 20, 5 );
function my_post_thumbnail_fallback( $html, $post_id, $post_thumbnail_id, $size, $attr ) {
    if ( empty( $html ) ) {
        $image = get_children( "post_parent={$post_id}&post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&numberposts=1" );
        if($image){
                foreach ($image as $attachment_id => $attachment) {
                        $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id);
                 return printf(
                                 '<img src="%s" height="%s" width="%s" />'
                                ,$src[0]
                                ,get_option( 'thumbnail_size_w' )
                                ,get_option( 'thumbnail_size_h' )
                                );
            }
         } 
         else {
               return printf(
                                 '<img src="%s" height="%s" width="%s" />'
                                ,get_template_directory_uri().'/images/featured/featured.jpg'
                                ,get_option( 'thumbnail_size_w' )
                                ,get_option( 'thumbnail_size_h' )
                                );
         }  
    } 
        return $html;
}
```

**Another solution that I found in [this article](http://wpforce.com/automatically-set-the-featured-image-in-wordpress/) and it's based on different `action hooks` does thing as intended which displays(sets) first attachment image in post as featured or in last case scenario displays(sets) default image as post's featured image:**

```
function autoset_featured() {
          global $post;
          $already_has_thumb = has_post_thumbnail($post->ID);
              if (!$already_has_thumb)  {
              $attached_image = get_children( "post_parent=$post->ID&post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&numberposts=1" );
                          if ($attached_image) {
                                foreach ($attached_image as $attachment_id => $attachment) {
                                set_post_thumbnail($post->ID, $attachment_id);
                                }
                           } else {
                                set_post_thumbnail($post->ID, '414');
                           }
                        }
      }  //end function
add_action('the_post', 'autoset_featured');
add_action('save_post', 'autoset_featured');
add_action('draft_to_publish', 'autoset_featured');
add_action('new_to_publish', 'autoset_featured');
add_action('pending_to_publish', 'autoset_featured');
add_action('future_to_publish', 'autoset_featured');
```

Now.. I do like that `post_thumbnail_html` `filter hook` solution and am intrigued by it not working.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: _"but without success"_ is no proper problem description. Please add more information.

Comment: When featured image is missing nothing is displayed. Thank you.

Comment: Please always add such infos to the question, as not all people read comments - we just got too many questions/answers :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the `post_thumbnail_html` filter hook which passes 5 variables to your hooked function :

- `$html` - the Output html of the post thumbnail
- `$post_id` - the post ID.
- `$post_thumbnail_id` - the attachment id of the image
- `$size` - the size requested or default
- `$attr` - Query string or array of attributes.

So something like:

```
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'my_post_thumbnail_fallback', 20, 5 );
function my_post_thumbnail_fallback( $html, $post_id, $post_thumbnail_id, $size, $attr ) {
    if ( empty( $html ) ) {
        // return you fallback image either from post of default as html img tag.
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at above post and tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thats perfect. Love it

Answer (score 4):

*As an addition to @Bainternet answer:*

Retrieve the set size from the options table. This means, the returned image will align with all user settings. Calls the default thumb only from the **template** directory to get around cases where child themes are present and won't have the thumbnail.

```
/**
 * Default post thumbnail image.
 * 
 * @param  string $html The Output HTML of the post thumbnail
 * @param  int $post_id The post ID
 * @param  int $post_thumbnail_id The attachment id of the image
 * @param  string $size The size requested or default
 * @param  mixed string/array $attr Query string or array of attributes
 * @return string $html the Output HTML of the post thumbnail
 */
function wpse64763_post_thumbnail_fb( $html, $post_id, $post_thumbnail_id, $size, $attr )
{
    if ( empty( $html ) )
    {
        return sprintf(
            '<img src="%s" height="%s" width="%s" />',
            get_template_directory_uri().'/path/to/default-thumb.png',
            get_option( 'thumbnail_size_w' ),
            get_option( 'thumbnail_size_h' )
        );
    }

    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'wpse64763_post_thumbnail_fb', 20, 5 );
```

Comment: Please take a look at above post and tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There you go, just tested and like this work fine for me ;)

```
    add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'wc_post_thumbnail_fallback', 20, 5 );
function wc_post_thumbnail_fallback( $html, $post_id, $post_thumbnail_id, $size, $attr ) {
   if ($html) {
        return $html;
    }else {
        $args = array(
            'numberposts' => 1,
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'post_mime_type' => 'image',
            'post_parent' => $post_id,
            'post_status' => null,
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
        );

        $images = get_children($args);

        if ($images) {
            foreach ($images as $image) {
                return wp_get_attachment_image($image->ID, $size);
            }
        }else{
            printf('<img src="%s" height="%s" width="%s" />'
                ,get_template_directory_uri().'/images/featured/featured.jpg'
                ,get_option( 'thumbnail_size_w' )
                ,get_option( 'thumbnail_size_h' ));
        }

    }
}
```